# Discord.py counts down until adding Role A when a member sends a message while having Role B. Role A gets added even if role B has been taken away

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Currently when someone sends a message and has the "Hunger" role, the bot gives them a countdown role (to stop the counting to repeat) and counts 60 seconds, then gives them the "dead" role. However, after the timer is done, it gives the "dead" role even if "hunger" has been taken away which I only want to happen if the user still has "hunger".

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  Hunger = message.guild.get_role(957207332134223892)
  Counting = message.guild.get_role(957525791426637834)
  Dead = message.guild.get_role(852087847917715457)
  if Hunger in message.author.roles:
    if Counting not in message.author.roles:
      if Dead not in message.author.roles:
        await message.author.add_roles(Counting)
        time.sleep(60)
        if Hunger in message.author.roles:
          await message.author.add_roles(Dead)
        await message.author.remove_roles(Counting)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. Use `asyncio.sleep()` instead:

```
import asyncio

@bot.command()
async def role(ctx):
    Hunger = ctx.guild.get_role(957207332134223892)
    Counting = ctx.guild.get_role(957525791426637834)
    Dead = ctx.guild.get_role(852087847917715457)
    if Hunger in ctx.author.roles:
        if Counting not in ctx.author.roles:
            if Dead not in ctx.author.roles:
                await ctx.author.add_roles(Counting)
                await asyncio.sleep(60)
                await ctx.author.remove_roles(Counting)
                if Hunger in ctx.author.roles:
                    await ctx.author.add_roles(Dead)
```